# how to get registry key without having administrator rights in windows 7 OS

Tags: c#, .net

In my application(windows C#.net) i am trying to get the registry key. In windows XP(with and without admin rights) it is working fine and in windows 7 with admin rights it is working fine. But in windows 7 without admin rights when i try to get the registry key, the aplication is getting crash.

I am using the following code to get the registry key

Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rgKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(rgPath);

Can some help to get the registry key without admin rights in windows 7.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you are creating Registry key not getting it ?

Comment: What's the exception that gets thrown?

Comment: Your code isn't *get*ting anything, you're creating a registry key with that line. Why is this tagged "asp.net" ?

Comment: You cannot write to the registry unless the user running your application has the correct privileges. You can escalate the application to have the privilege to write to the registry provided it is escalated by an user who has said privilege.  This question shows no effort to research possible solutions.

Answer (score 3):

It could not be done in Windows7 without admin rights.

Here is the solution for it.

Open the project and go to proejct menu and select add new item. There will be an item with the name "Application Manifest File". Add this to your project. A file looking like xml will be opened.

Search for the following line in that file.

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

and replace it with this line

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Save the file and rebuild the solution. Now your software will ask for the administrator rights each time before executing on Windows7.

Enjoy :)

Comment: I can, login as admin or use windows impersonating, anyway your code has to run with user that have rights to do this